# Induction Cooking Power Stage and EMI Filter Schematic

Tags: power-supply, power, igbt, induction-heater

Recently I am planning to build an induction cooktop using half-bridge resonant topology. For a start, I took a look into ST evaluation board for induction cooking and wondering some part. Here is the link to the application note for the board: [AN2383 ST](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/102477/Kochfeld.pdf).

[image: AN2383 Power Stage]

What is the purpose of R1 and R5?

Comment: R1 is bleeder for C1, C4 and C5.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Okay got it. How about the R5?

Comment: It's unclear what R5 is used for and, isn't helped by the downwards arrow not indicating the node it connects to.

Comment: Hi Andy. From the app notes, it seems the downward arrow connected to the DC link ground in the resonant inverter stage. They didn't show us a complete look to the schematic in the app notes. That's why I am confused.

Comment: There just isn't enough information in the linked document to build this circuit unfortunately and, I'm not impressed by the shoddy use of that downward arrow. I think you should contact them if you are trying to recreate it if only to get a much better spec of the resonant capacitors C13 and C14.